# How to get and set text android?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-edittext

I'm trying to get the text from one android edit text and put it in another, the whole over all goal is to make a temperature converter. It's an assignment from an online course I'm working on which I paid for.

Anyways this my code I'm using in my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText txt_Input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Input1);
    Button btnConvert1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvertOne);
    final EditText txt_Output1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Output1);

    btnConvert1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            //txt_Output1.setText(txt_Input1.getText().toString());
            //txt_Output1.setText(Integer.parseInt(txt_Input1.getText().toString()));
            userInput = txt_Input1.getText().toString();
            Log.v("TEST", userInput);
        }
    });

    EditText txt_Input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Input2);
    Button btnConvert2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvertTwo);
    EditText txt_Output2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Output2);

    btnConvert2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

        }
    });

}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong I've tried it a couple different ways and so far none have helped, I'm not really sure why but if I don't set the edit texts as final it won't let me call them in my btnConvert1 method. Does anyone know how to fix this? I really want to know what I'm doing wrong. Right now if I hit the btnConver1 this is the output I get:

> 01-07 00:56:11.549  26996-26996/application.helloword.tobar.jose.temperatureconverterapp V/TEST﹕ [ 01-07 00:56:11.809   768: 1129 I/AudioService ]
>       getStreamVolume 3 index 0

Comment: I didn't post all of the code but I would not mind doing so if it is necessary. It's just a beginning assignment.

Comment: `It's just a beginning assignment`. Please note that SO is not a place for your assignments. Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: [How to ask a good question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's not homework, I pay for the class there is no grade of certificate it's like a paid youtube tutorial site with assignments that you do and grade yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String str = editText.getText().toString();
 editText.setText("your name is " + str);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I've tried it.


        btnConvert1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                //txt_Output1.setText(txt_Input1.getText().toString());
                //txt_Output1.setText(Integer.parseInt(txt_Input1.getText().toString()));
                String userInput = txt_Input1.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("TEST"+userInput);
            }
        });
it prints out the word "TEST" but not anything in userInput.

Comment: Please elaborate what you are currently doing. What you are actually facing.?

Comment: At the moment, I just want to take the text from txt_Input1 and put it into txt_Output1. For some reason nothing I do is working it will just print out blank. The button works fine but I don't know why txt_Input1.getText().toString() is not working. You're not the only one suggesting it but it's not working I don't know why.